# Twilio AutorizeURL - can it pass my User ID back to me when my Customer clicks the Connect Button?

Tags: twilio

How can I identify which customer to associate the AccountSid parameter with when my AuthorizeURL script has been called by Twilio?

Can I attach some ID info to the URL in the Connect Button HTML that I place on my page, and expect that parameter to be passed along to my AuthorizeURL?

(I'm building this in PHP)

Comment: Including code is encouraged (I don't know Twilio so I can't comment on whether it is needed for this question)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio support responded to an email from me. Their reply was:

> If you add a query string parameter called "state" to the target url of the connect button Twilio will pass that parameter back to your AuthorizedRedirectUrl. This is useful for passing metadata, like a customer username or unique identifier, to your authorize url.

So I consider this closed.